# Symfony - Filtering join causes the query to return nothing

Tags: mysql, symfony, join, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I'm trying to perform a query that returns the events that're approved and not booked by the current user.

When i perform this query I get no events returned where it should return on event which is not booked by the current user.

```
 public function getAvailableEvents(UserInterface $user)
    {
        $q = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('
                    select v from Tsk\FEBundle\Entity\Event v
                    left join v.attendance a where a.id != :user
                    and v.is_approved = true
                ');
        $q->setParameter("user", $user);
        return $q->execute();
    }
```

Here's my two entities `User` and `Event` specific part for this relation.

`User` :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Event", inversedBy="attendance", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_events",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="event_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
 protected $booked_events;
```

`Event` entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="booked_events")
 */
 protected $attendance;
```

Comment: What database do you use? Is it MySQL?

Comment: @VisioN Yes it's mysql.

Comment: While this is not the case for MySQL but *probably* the issue is in non standard use of *"not equal"*, which should be `<>` and not `!=`.

Comment: @VisioN Hmm, I've replaced `!=` with `<>` but still returns nothing.

Comment: This may also be related but what if you try to pass the user's `id` as a parameter but not the entity itself: `->setParameter('user', $user->getId())`? Usually `WHERE a != $user` or `WHERE a.id != $user->getId()` works fine but I never combined both, as you have.

Comment: @VisioN Yea I've tried that. I even tried to hard code the user `id` just for testing but still no good.

Comment: Then you don't have approved events with other users in the database `:)`

Comment: @VisioN Do you mean there has to be another booked events by other users for this user to get a result ? If so, How to make the join statement optional (i.e. return events that's not booked by the current user IF ANY, and that're approved too)

Comment: I guess this is the logic that is applied to your query: you get approved events, which are not attended by the current user.

Comment: @VisioN But the query checks if no users attend a certain event, it excludes it. Which is not what I want. I want to return events that's not attended by anyone too.

Comment: Ah, then in the query you may just use the following: `WHERE a IS NULL`.

Comment: @VisioN Thanks! I don't know how I forgot this. You can put is as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed, the problem appears to be in a query. If you want to get events which are not attended by anyone, you may use `WHERE a IS NULL` condition.